# Can't get Ethernet to work - Lubuntu

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, ethernet

I've got my lubuntu config 99% there as my media centre PC.

It's working over wireless, but unfortunately due to the wireless card being a bit old-school, it's only performing on wireless G. Hence my need to use ethernet.

On connecting the ethernet cable, it works sometimes for a few minutes before dieing out.

I ran an `ifconfig` and the adapter is showing, as well as my wireless one:

```
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:42:49:0f:c9:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 3428 (3.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 998  bytes 89499 (89.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 998  bytes 89499 (89.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet [blanked]  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast [blanked]
        inet6 fe80::9e5a:58c5:1c7f:d9a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 78:dd:08:c6:1f:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 530486  bytes 699047786 (699.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 122963  bytes 12368055 (12.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I've looked at the interfaces file and I see no mention of either the wireless or the wired:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I've also had a look in the networkmanager.conf file. And changed `managed=true`. This did nothing:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Appreciated in advance if anyone could help me out please?

---

Just and FYI - I've tested this on a windows machine and have faith that it's not a hardware issue

---

As requested, I've changed the NetworkManager.conf file back to it's original state.

And then output the following:

```
jay@VaioServer:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 78:dd:08:c6:1f:76
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.8.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:e7a00000-e7a0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8057 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:42:49:0f:c9:46
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 memory:e5220000-e5223fff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:e5200000-e521ffff
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58443/discussion-on-question-by-jay-cant-get-ethernet-to-work-lubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

We did a `sudo lshw -C Network` and discovered that the ethernet interface was not making a proper link ("**link=no** multicast=yes port=twisted pair **speed=10Mbit/s**"). This suggested a cable or other hardware problem.

By re-cabling the ethernet port on the computer directly to the cable/dsl modem, and power cycling the modem, and rebooting the computer... it worked!

This left other cables, or the router as suspect.

After re-cabling, we power cycled the modem, then the router, rebooted the computer, and it all came up working now! The problem was either the cable from the router to the computer, or the router itself.

**Update:**

Final determination... an intermittent connection at the ethernet jack on the laptop. Recommend just trying another ethernet cable, or resoldering the joints under the jack on the printed circuit.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, I lost all my Network capability. I could get it to work temporarily but to get it to come up on boot I manually edited the interface file `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and added these entries...

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

(In your case it would be `enp4s0`)

Comment: I've tried this already. but upon trying to restart network manager, I just time out.

Comment: Also what I don't understand, is why isn't wlan not there. As that's working already?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot? I'm really no expert but it did work for me.

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to try that, just yesterday I made some network config. I restarted the networking service and network manager, both failed on me. So I decided to a hard reboot. Upon doing that, I couldn't even get into the OS anymore. I had to go via recovery, drop into root and all that jazz. If you're sure, I'll do it. I just don't want to go through another one of those recovery sessions.

Comment: You will have to reboot eventually....That issue needs tackled as well.

Comment: Thanks @Jos, How did you do that? I tried the code tag.... :)

Comment: Okay, I gave it a shot. Didn't work :( same issue

Comment: Select a block of code and press `{}` ;-) Works for whole lines as well as for code within a text paragraph.

Comment: This change caused my machine to stop booting after a power cycle. I had to go into recovery mode and comment out these changes to make my machine boot again.

Comment: OK, sorry good luck.

Comment: Appreciate you trying to help :D