# WiFi not connecting in Ubuntu 14.04 (Dual boot)

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot

My Sys Spec: HP-Laptop (Pavilion Notebook)
Os         : Window 10(Original with Laptop) , Ubuntu-14.04 (Dual Boot)

My system has dual boot, Windows-10 and Ubuntu-14.04. After installing ubuntu, I am unable to see Wifi Connections and unable to connect to Wifi (Wireless) Connections. However I am able to connect through Wired (LAN) Connections

This issue is not there in Window-10. Its working fine in Windows-10.

Can anyone help me on this please ?

Comment: run `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and post it here

Comment: # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Add these lines by running `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`          
 >auto wlan0  >iface wlan0 inet dhcp

Comment: I got a file /etc/network/interfaces
 with options like read , write , next page etc... at the bottom and curser being place after these lines "# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
"

Comment: No problem..Its working for me

Comment: sorry , i didnt get you...
 
Those 2 additions go on separate lines??

Comment: auto command not found..SO I removed auto and typed rest ..Now got wlan0 command not found
No command 'auto' found, did you mean:
 Command 'uuto' from package 'uucp' (universe)
auto: command not found

Comment: Have you ever used Nano?

Comment: did not work ...

Comment: Look at these answers, similar question...https://askubuntu.com/questions/912833/cant-get-ethernet-to-work-lubuntu/912852#912852

Answer (score 1):

Run this command on terminal:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

If you are getting:

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) auto lo iface lo inet loopback
```

Your problem is sorted ,you have to just add two lines:
Run on terminal :

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then add these two lines at the end

```
auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
Then type <kbd>y</kbd> to say yes for saving the file and then press enter
Restart your system.